# Jquery with WCF

Tags: jquery, wcf

I am trying to get my jquery code work with WCF.
I am starting out with something very simple. The WCF service is hosted on the IIS.
It has a simple interface and a simple implementation. Following is my WCF code.

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IEvalService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetId",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetId();
  }
```

The implementation of the above the interface is as follows:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=
AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class EvalService: IEvalService
{

    public string GetId()
    {
        BenchMarkStatus benchMarkStatus = new BenchMarkStatus();         
        return benchMarkstatus.Name;
    }
}
```

Of course there is a benchMark class as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class BenchMarkStatus
{
    private string _name;

    public BenchMarkStatus()
    {
        _name = "Sudarshan";
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The config file for the Webservice is as follows:

```
<services>
  <service name="BenchMarkServiceLiabrary.EvalService">
    <endpoint address="10.66.26.171"         
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="BenchMarkServiceLiabrary.IEvalService"  
              behaviorConfiguration="WEB" />
   </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WEB">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
                           aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

And on the client side I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "http://10.66.26.171/EvalService/Eval.svc/GetId?callback=?",
          contentType: "json/application; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
          success: function (data) { alert(data) }
      });
function jsonCallback() {
          alert("me");
}
```

I am getting a 404 error. Initially I had issues with Cross domain stuff...but now The GetId function cannot be accessed from the Client code. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you get the 404 error if you browse the service url?

Comment: What happens if you just hit the service in your browser: `http://10.66.26.171/EvalService/Eval.svc/GetId`? Since you aren't sending or receiving `BenchMarkStatus` it doesn't need to be marked with `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes - it's not a part of your Service Contract.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the address part of the service in web.config

Because you are hosting in iis, your service will be available in:

`http://localhost/EvalService/Eval.svc` (localhost if your iis is running locally or if not, the ip or address of the remote iis)

This would be the address of your service's endpoint hadn't you added the address part in web.config, with the added address part you can find that endpoint in `http://localhost/EvalService/Eval.svc/10.66.26.171`

If you only have one endpoint you can safely omit or just have address="" in your service configuration and access your service at this address `http://localhost/EvalService/Eval.svc`:

```
 <service name="BenchMarkServiceLiabrary.EvalService">
    <endpoint address=""         
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="BenchMarkServiceLiabrary.IEvalService"  
              behaviorConfiguration="WEB" />
   </service>
```

Answer (score -1):

StackOverflow does Suggest some old Questions; I really hope you moved over to WebAPI by now, It's a lot easier. Every time I've tried setting up a wcf Service it's been a fight. But regarding the Question; I had a very similar issue a while ago, And adding  to the EndpointBehaviors solved it for me.

Try updating your endPointBehaviors to the following

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WEB">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```